# Javascript Split wont work when there are no characters to split

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<div id="code1" data-code="123;12"></div>
<div id="code2" data-code="231"></div>
```

Jquery/Javascript

```
alert($("#code1").data("code").split(";")[0]);
alert($("#code2").data("code").split(";")[0]);
alert('test');
```

Since code2 does not have a ";", the code stops working all together. The last alert will not work nor will any code after the non-splitable code. How can I split code by ";" even when it may not have the ";" character?

Comment: `alert("231".split(";")[0])` prints `231` for me. What does it print for you, and what browser are you testing in?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Seems in chrome it's getting a [`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).split is not a function` in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr5ku1zk/1/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek that makes sense... jQuery created typecast to number in `data()` a while back if it is numeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data()` will typecast a value to number if it is numeric

Try:

```
$("#code2").data("code").toString().split(';')
```

More about typecasting in the html 5 attributes section of [data() docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
alert($("#code1").attr("data-code").split(";")[0]);
alert($("#code2").attr("data-code").split(";")[0]);
alert('test');
```

The reason that the second line fails is because the value is implicitly typecasted to a `number` by jQuery when using `$.data`. It has nothing to do with the implementation of `String.prototype.split`, since that returns an array with the 0th element being the full string if the delimiter does not exist.

In order to fix the problem, use `$.attr` instead of `$.data` to ensure that jQuery does not internally typecast the value to another type if it looks like another type.

Test on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr5ku1zk/2/).